# pipelines and release vs snapshot builds

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to use jenkins pipelines for continuous integration, but not cd, I am still using the snapshot and release model of maven.
How to cause the pipeline to execute a release build or a snapshot build depending on some condition?
Also, how do you trigger some things like testing on other platforms, integration tests, etc only sometimes? I do not want long tests and resource hungry booting on windows to go each time I commit.

Comment: What kind of condition do you want to use at "some condition"?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by ` I do not want long tests and resource hungry booting on windows to go each time I commit.`.

Comment: I mean, integration tests are resource intensive, and booting a windows vm to perform another set of tests to check if the project still builds on windows is even more resource intensive, I believe. As for conditions, for example, I would like to trigger full builds with windows testing and integration tests only in case of, for example, nightly build or when the build was manually triggered

Comment: Do you need to run the tests on a Windows machine? Why not having the Windows machine as Jenkins Node available..?

Comment: well a windows vm is a jenkins node. and when my project will include windows parts, I would need a job that would run tests on it, but I do not want for it to happen every time I commit due to resources. I have this vm on the same physical server where master is deployed, and I could live with it running for each commit, but do not want to do it if not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the not-so-trivial world of continuous integration. When you use the traditional way of *manually* triggering builds on the build server, you can choose whether you build

- a SNAPSHOT to play with and show to colleagues
- a release, which should go to production if it passes all the tests.

In pure CI, every commit should be a possible release so the distinction between the above two becomes difficult. You can - and I some people do it - only produce SNAPSHOT builds when doing automatic commit-triggers-build building. Then the builds are only for feedback, but not meant to be used later on. This also makes it easier to delete them when your hard disc complains. In this scenario, you would start the release builds manually.

If you want to be more CI-like, you can consider every commit as potential release and give a release number. Whether you run all the tests is up to you. If your tests take too long, you can tell Jenkins that your automatic pipeline only runs up to a "alpha" level and that the "alpha to beta" pipeline is still started manually if necessary.

Some people will say that you should always run all the tests and keep all the versions, and that hardware is cheap and you could easily build a cluster. These people probably have never seen the inside of large, bureaucratic companies.

Comment: isn't "every commit is a possible release" already something continuous delivery is about? I noted before that I don't do cd, just ci

Answer (score 1):

One way we do this is based on Branch names. We have release branches in git such as `v1.0_release`, and we also have integ branches: `v1.0_integ`.

We setup a multibranch pipeline with a `when` clause on the branch name. When the branch name is `*_release`, we deliver that build to the release artifact repo. Other branches go to the snapshot repo.

Anytime any other branch is pushed to git (such as feature branches), they are also built, and depending on the application, we usually just archive these builds in Jenkins. This gives developers quick feedback on any branch they use and easy access to artifacts.

Developers can play with any code in any branches they want, and when they like the code and are ready to build a release candidate, they push to the release branch and Jenkins just takes care of it.

Comment: ahh well, may be a nice idea. But isn't deploying to snapshot/release repository more related to the fact that version ends with -SNAPSHOT or not maven side? so it could be another condition to check, even though if I would like to have branches for releases, then that idea would work nicely, I think.

Comment: I'm ops much more than I'm dev. But I think Artifactory handles snapshot repos differently than release repos. Things get deleted out of snapshot repos regularly, but kept in release repos. But either way, whether you change the version on the files, or publish to a different place, you can still use the same technique. This is just a technique I setup for some of our developers based on our artifactory configuration and how the developers work.

Comment: I meant that maven selects deploying to a snapshot or non snapshot repository, when they are separated, based on version. But yes, I see the use for this technique. So what is left is the problem of not running some tests on each commit. Although maybe it is a better idea to run them, not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

What I have decided is: I do not differentiate between builds with and without integration tests. they would run long especially that they run on windows and linux, but not sure if I have a reason to do it another way, what you think?

As for differentiating between snapshot and release builds: maven uses profiles to perform special actions on a release or not. but, when it goes for deciding between deploying to snapshot vs release repository in distributionManagement, maven would use version number to check where to deploy. Because you cannot activate a profile based on current project version, I decided to merge this, because if you have a snapshot version, you certainly do not release, and if your pom has a release version, you do not build snapshots. So release is triggered by manually setting pom to a release version and committing, at which point the ci would read pom, check if version ends with "-SNAPSHOT", and if not, will activate a release profile and do other release only things, like it will deploy a maven site.